# If else in bash script for shell command

Tags: bash, shell

I have written a bash script that does not show any errors. However I would like to add conditional block list if success then show email success else show error message in email as shown in the code below.

```
scp -i id_rsa -r testuser@1.1.1.:/data1/scp ~/data/scp/files 
success >> ~/data/scp/files/log.txt 2>&1 
if success 
then 
| mail -s "Download 
Successfull" abc@test.com <<< "Files Successfully Downloaded" 
else 
 | mail -s "Error: Download Failed" abc@test.com <<< "Error File download 
 Failed!"
 fi
```

Here is the working script without If else block

```
#!/module/for/bash
 scp -i id_rsa -r test@1.1.1.1:/data1/scp ~/data/scp/files 
 echo success! >> ~/data/scp/files/log.txt 2>&1 | mail -s "Download 
 Successfull" abc@test.com <<< "Files Successfully 
 Downloaded" | mail -s "Error: Download Failed" abc@test.com <<< 
 "Error:file download Failed!"
```

Comment: I googled `if else bash` and got tons of relevant results. What is your question exactly?

Comment: @HFBrowning please see updated question I am getting format error

Comment: Your `then` and `else` branches start with pipes; you aren’t allowed to do that. If you want to pipe into a conditional, the pipe needs to go before the `if`; I don’t remember if you also need to enclose the entire conditional `if`…`else`…`fi` block in a subshell.

Comment: You seem to have some additional line breaks, such as the one in the middle of one of your string literals. Please copy and paste your exact code, even if some of the lines are long. Is `success` a command?

Comment: @KeithThompson I have added all code. Basically I want that if success is true then if should run and other wise else. Working Example of script without if is updated in question please see that to get idea what I want

Comment: It sounds like you want the output of the scp to go to the email in any case.  The simplest thing to do would be: `{ if scp ... 2>&1 ; then echo "SUCCESS"; else echo FAILURE; fi; } | mail ...`  but honestly it would be cleaner to just do `scp ... 2>&1 | mail ...`

Comment: You have the string `"Download Successfull"` split across two lines. That's legal, but strange; is it really split like that in your script? What is `success`? Is it a function? A command? How is it defined? You seem to be trying to determine whether your `scp` command was successful or not; the word `success` is not the way to do that. The shell has no idea what the word `success` means.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The scp man page states: `The scp utility exits 0 on success, and >0 if an error occurs.`

So you can do something like:

```
if scp -i id_rsa -r testuser@1.1.1.:/data1/scp ~/data/scp/files
then
    mail -s "Download Successful" abc@test.com <<<"Files Downloaded"
else
    mail -s "Download Error" abc@test.com <<<"Download error"
fi
```

or

```
scp -i id_rsa -r testuser@1.1.1.:/data1/scp ~/data/scp/files
if [[ $? -eq 0 ]]
then
    mail -s "Download Successful" abc@test.com <<<"Files Downloaded"
else
    mail -s "Download Error" abc@test.com <<<"Download error"
fi
```

finally you may also want to look at something like storing the scp output. Use -q to have scp not print out progress meters and what not:

```
MYOUT=$(scp -q -i id_rsa -r testuser@1.1.1.:/data1/scp ~/data/scp/files 2>&1)
if [[ $? -eq 0 ]]
then
    mail -s "Download Successful" abc@test.com <<<"$MYOUT"
else
    mail -s "Download Error" abc@test.com <<<"$MYOUT"
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

This [link](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_07_02.html) should clear the air. Hope it helped!

Answer (score 0):

@Korthrun has already posted several ways to accomplish what I think you're trying to do; I'll take a look at what's going wrong in your current script. You seem to be confused about a couple of basic elements of shell scripting: pipes (`|`) and testing for command success/failure.

Pipes are used to pass the output of one command into the input of another (and possibly then chain the output of the second command into the input of a third command, etc). But when you use a pipe string like this:

```
echo success! >> ~/data/scp/files/log.txt 2>&1 | 
mail -s "Download Successfull" abc@test.com <<< "Files Successfully Downloaded" |
mail -s "Error: Download Failed" abc@test.com <<< "Error:file download Failed!"
```

the pipes aren't actually doing anything. The first pipe tries to take the output of `echo` and feed it to the input of `mail`, but the `>>` in the `echo` command sends its output to a file instead, so no actual data is sent to the `mail` command. Which is probably good, because the `<<<` on the `mail` command tells it to ignore the regular input (from the pipe) and feed a string as input instead! Similarly, the second pipe tries to feed the output from the first `mail` command (there isn't any) to the last `mail` command, but again it's ignored due to another `<<<` input string. The correct way to do this is simply to remove the pipes, and run each command separately:

```
echo success! >> ~/data/scp/files/log.txt 2>&1
mail -s "Download Successfull" abc@test.com <<< "Files Successfully Downloaded"
mail -s "Error: Download Failed" abc@test.com <<< "Error:file download Failed!"
```

This is also causing a problem in the other version of your script, where you use:

```
if success 
then 
| mail -s "Download Successfull" abc@test.com <<< "Files Successfully Downloaded"
```

Here, there's no command before the pipe, so it doesn't make any sense at all (and you get a shell syntax error). Just remove the pipe.

Now, about success/failure testing: you seem to be using `success` as a command, but it isn't one. You can either use the command you want to check the success of directly as the `if` conditional:

```
if scp ...; then
    echo "It worked!"
else
    echo "It failed!"
fi
```

or use the shell variable `$?` which returns the exit status of the last command (success=0, failure=anything else):

```
scp ...
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    ...
```

There's a subtlety here that's easy to miss: the thing after `if` is a command, but in the second form it appears to be a logical expression (testing whether `$?` is equal to `0`). The secret is that `[` is actually a command that evaluates logical expressions and then exits with success or failure depending on whether the expression was true or false. Do not mistake `[ ]` for some sort of parentheses or other grouping operator, that's not what's going on here!

BTW, the `[[ ]]` form that Korthrun used is very similar to `[ ]`, but isn't supported by more basic shells. It does avoid some nasty syntax oddities with `[ ]`, though, so if you're using `bash` it's a good way to go.

Also, note that `$?` gives the status of the last command executed, so it gets reset by every single command that executes. For example, this won't work:

```
scp ...
echo "scp's exit status was $?"
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then      # Don't do this!!!!
```

...because the `if` is then looking at the exit status of the `echo` command, not `scp`! If you need to do something like this, store the status in a variable:

```
scp ...
scpstatus=$?
echo "scp's exit status was $scpstatus"
if [ $scpstatus -eq 0 ]; then
```